# Does the Ryll-Nardzewski theorem hold for weak-star topology?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Conway's functional analysis proves the existence of Haar measures. One of the points of proof is to utilize the Ryll-Nardzewski fixed point theorem, which states that a semigroup of weakly continuous affine maps defined on the weakly compact convex subset of locally convex space has a fixed point if it satisfies the nonctracting condition.

However, in the proof, I confirmed that the **weak-star** continuous affine map defined in the **weak-star** compact set is utilized, not the **weak**ly continuous affine map defined in the **weak**ly compact set. Is this an error in Conway's book, or is it because the Ryll-Nardzewski theorem still holds for weak-star topology?

** The locally convex space in the proof is a space of complex regular Borel measure, where the weak topology does not coincides weak star topology, since it is the dual of continuous functions, which is not reflexive Banach space in general.

Comment: The weak$^*$-topology $\sigma(X^*,X)$ on the dual $X^*$ of any locally convex space is the weak topology of $(X^*,\sigma(X^*,X))$ because the dual of this space is $X$ (or, more precisely, the set of evaluations $\delta_x$ with $x\in X$). You can thus apply the Ryll-Nardzewski theorem to the locally convex space $(X^*,\sigma(X^*,X))$.

Comment: Let me first fix the notation. Do you mean the weak topology $(X^*, \sigma(X^*, X^{**}))$ ? ($X^*, \sigma(X^*, X^{**})$ is weak topology on $X^*$ and $(X^*, \sigma(X^*, X^{}))$ is a weak*-topology on $X^*$). And, I don't think two topologies are identical in $X^*$ unless $X$ is a reflexive space. (Conway, A Course in Functional Analysis, page 132.)

Comment: Writing $X^{**}$ requires to have a specified topology on $X^*$. Banach spacers usually means the dual norm topology and then it is true that $\sigma(X^*,X^{**})=\sigma(X^*,X)$ if and only if $X$ is reflexive. However, the dual of $(X^*,\sigma(X^*,X))$ is always equal to $X$ and thus $\sigma(X^*,(X^*,\sigma(X^*,X))^*)=\sigma(X^*,X)$.